# Get template rendered from controller without render yet

Tags: json, templates, grails, render

I want to return my response as JSON with ajax containing more atributtes instead only the template:

Default:

```
render(template:"/templates/question",model:[question: question])
```

..and want something like:

```
def template = *get*(template:"/templates/question",model:[question: question])
    render [template:template, isTemplate: true] as JSON
```

Is that possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Typically you would use JSONBuilder and a template wouldn't really come into the picture.  Maybe I have misunderstood your question...

Comment: guess find the solution: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=10815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the solution is:

```
class MyController { 
  def test = {
        // stored as string ... 
        def x = g.render(template:"/basecontroller/test",model:[name:"wysmedia.com"]); 
        render(x); // display the template instead render 
  }
}
```